# sbt-docker difference between add and addRaw

Tags: scala, docker, sbt, sbt-docker

The title says it all: sbt-docker plugin examples use both add() and addRaw(), but the documentation only mentions add(). What is addRaw() for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there is none, for the most recent version of sbt-docker, "add()" has being tag as deprecated, so you should use "addRaw()" instead.

[Here is the source code](https://github.com/marcuslonnberg/sbt-docker/blob/master/src/main/scala/sbtdocker/DockerfileCommands.scala#LC182).

Comment: Agreed. The most helpful thing is to try add() or addRaw() and then look at the Dockerfile that the plugin creates under target/docker and see what the commands do.